# Why does a ORA-12054 error occur when creating this simple materialized view example?

Tags: oracle, plsql, view, materialized-views

```
ALTER TABLE RECORDINGS ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON RECORDINGS TABLESPACE USERS NOLOGGING;

DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW REC_SEARCH_TEST;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW REC_SEARCH_TEST
REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, TITLE FROM RECORDINGS
);


ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view
```

Cannot understand what is wrong here, I know that if I take out the DISTINCT clause it works, but why can I not use 'DISTINCT' if I specify 'REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT' which is required.

If I use DISTINCT and REFRESH on demand there is no problem, but these are not the requirements.

Comment: You have a unique index. There's no need for the distinct so why bother with it?

Comment: Perhaps the example isn't the best, because I want to expand the view to a more complicated query that will require a distinct keyword, right now I am just trying to get it working on a basic level.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` does not make any sense at all. The `ID` column in the select will cause all rows to be distinct always.

Comment: Okay, good point for the OP.  I happened across here 8 years later, and I had a case where I *did* need a `DISTINCT`, so this solved my problem; just cannot use `ON COMMIT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like with the addition of the DISTINCT, you've made your view's underlying SQL ineligible for fast refresh, and therefore not able to be used with ON COMMIT (even tho you specify refresh complete instead of refresh fast).  From [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm):

> The two refresh execution modes are ON COMMIT and ON DEMAND. Depending
>   on the materialized view you create, some of the options may not be
>   available. Table 8-4 describes the refresh modes.

Table 8-4 Refresh Modes

ON COMMIT

> Refresh occurs automatically when a transaction that modified one of
>   the materialized view's detail tables commits. **This can be specified
>   as long as the materialized view is fast refreshable** (in other words,
>   not complex). The ON COMMIT privilege is necessary to use this mode.

ON DEMAND

> Refresh occurs when a user manually executes one of the available
>   refresh procedures contained in the DBMS_MVIEW package (REFRESH,
>   REFRESH_ALL_MVIEWS, REFRESH_DEPENDENT).

The same document link has a list of restrictions for fast refresh as well.

Answer (score 1):

> "Perhaps the example isn't the best, because I want to expand the view
>   to a more complicated query that will require a distinct keyword,
>   right now I am just trying to get it working on a basic level. "

The DISTINCT is the cause of the ORA-12054.

```
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW REC_SEARCH_TEST
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT
    AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT empno, ename FROM emp
   )
/
  2    3    4    5    6  
       SELECT DISTINCT empno, ename FROM emp
                                         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view


Elapsed: 00:00:01.14
SQL> SQL> 
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW REC_SEARCH_TEST
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT
    AS (
       SELECT empno, ename FROM emp
   )
/
  2    3    4    5    6  
Materialized view created.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.33
SQL>
```

Why not start with a *something that works*?  Remove the DISTINCT.  Get your MView working.  Then complicate it later when it becomes necessary.

Although, as you already know you cannot use a DISTINCT you will have to revise either your query's logic or your refresh strategy.

Comment: For example if I am running a search and I want to populate a combo box.  I could keep a cache of the materialised view using "SELECT DISTINCT GENRE FROM APPS;".  Why can't a set up a materialised view like this to refresh on commit?  I know I can't but I'm interested in the reason and what other options are available.

Answer (score -1):

The important thing to note about the question is that it is **not** about fast refresh, but complete refresh. Thus, there is no logical reason that the usual restrictions for fast refresh on commit should apply, except the one that all referenced objects must be local.

The "refresh complete on commit is a relatively new feature, so the best answer to the "why" question is probably "Oracle has not yet implemented this fully, please check future versions of Oracle Database". Not very useful, but true...