# Materialized View cannot set on commit refresh

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I'm trying to create this materialized view based on another but keep getting the error:

```
Error report -
ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view
12054. 00000 -  "cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view"
*Cause:    The materialized view did not satisfy conditions for refresh at
           commit time.
*Action:   Specify only valid options.
```

View:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS
    NOLOGGING
    BUILD IMMEDIATE 
    REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT WITH ROWID
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
    AS 
        SELECT AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID, MAX(AD.VERNUM) AS MAX_VERNUM, MIN(AD.DEFVERN) AS MAX_DEFVERN
        FROM   CSTST.MV_LLATTRDATA_PARTITIONED_TEST AD, DTREE DT -- dtree is a view
        WHERE AD.ID = DT.DATAID   
        GROUP BY AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID;
```

I have logs set up on the base tables, i'm not quite sure what else to check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a ORA-12054 error occur when creating this simple materialized view example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883662/why-does-a-ora-12054-error-occur-when-creating-this-simple-materialized-view-exa)

Answer (score 0):

There are certain restrictions which should be considered while creating fast refreshable MV with ROWID option.

> #### WITH ROWID Clause
>
> Specify WITH ROWID to create a rowid materialized view. Rowid materialized views are useful if the materialized view does not include all primary key columns of the master tables. Rowid materialized views must be based on a single table and cannot contain any of the following:
>
> Distinct or aggregate functions
>
> GROUP BY or CONNECT BY clauses
>
> Subqueries
>
> Joins
>
> Set operations

[CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302)

Comment: Oh crap, I'm going a group by and a join